# Set text with .innerHTML and change the href

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am getting the [website] from a pre-made plugin that I can't edit. If that element is empty I do not want to display anything, but if it has a url, I want to write the text 'Register Here' and have that link to the URL in [website]. Right now it is printing the text just fine, but not applying the href.

```
<p id="demo" ></p>
<script>

var str = "[website]";
var n = str.length;

if (n === 0) {
  alert("0");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Register Here";
  document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute ("href", 'str');
}
else {alert("else");}

</script>
```

Comment: Paragraphs have no href attribute.

Comment: And the line `setAttribute ("href", 'str');` won't work since you're passing in `str` as a string and not a variable. Remove the quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a>` instead of `<p>`.

```
<a id="demo" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Wow, that should have been my first clue. It is now appending it to the current site URL, rather than going to a whole new site. ie www.currentsite.com/www.newsite.com

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks!